# Regex for birthday date asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

What would be the regex for regexValidator for the field in which I would like to have date in format:

```
dd/MM/yyyy

dd - 01 - 31
MM - 01 - 12
yyyy - 1900 - 2012
```

Thank you very much for help

Comment: You do realize that you'll have to go back to that regex *every year*  and update it? Doesn't sound like a very good idea. Also, what if the user enters 31/02/1999?

Comment: Presumably you'd just use a stringbuilder to have a dynamic regex. You could then easily solve both problems.

Comment: Is there any difference between a normal date and a birthday date?

Comment: @leppie : a birthday date must be in the past.

Comment: @Rotem: And how does that affect the Regex for a date?

Comment: @leppie I think it just adds to the point of a Regex not being a good solution for validating a birthday date.

Comment: @Rotem: Or any other date. Now add culture to the mix and regex fails miserably ;p

Comment: @leppie You're absolutely right, I hadn't even considered culture.

Answer (score 3):

Your conditions don't necessarily satisfy a legitimate date. Consider the date 30/02/2012. A regex would let it pass validation, but there is no such date. I recommend you use `DateTime.TryParse` instead.

[DateTime.TryParse on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx)

edit: I now realize there is in fact a difference between a date and a birth date, in the sense that a birth date can not be in the future.

To enforce this in your validation, you should also make sure that the date is in the past using `CompareTo.DateTime.Now < 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the work client side and use the setFullYear function of Date to check if the date is valid.. I wrote this out for you, you could also use the regex provided to test the field before running the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkDate() {
    var content = document.regexForm.input.value;
    var splitResult = content.split("/");
    if(splitResult.length ==3){
        var day = splitResult[0];
        var mon = splitResult[1] - 1; //month is from 0-11 (0:jan,11:dec)
        var yr = splitResult[2];

        //create a new date object set full year with the params
        var myDate = new Date();
        myDate.setFullYear( yr, mon, day);   

        //the function takes in the strings and creates a valid date.. 
        //so if you pass in january 40, the new date is Feb 9th and the month is 02 not 01
        if(myDate.getMonth() != mon){
            alert("not valid");
        }
        else{
            alert("is valid");
        }

    }
    else{
        alert("not valid");
    }
}
</script>
<body>

<form name="regexForm">
dd/mm/yyyy <BR>
<input type="text" name="input">
<input type=button value="run test regex" onClick="checkDate();return true;">
</form>
```